# Enum.GetName() As Constant property

Tags: c#, enums, compiler-errors, constants

I have been working in C# for about 8 months so forgive me if this is dumb...

I have an enum that I will need the string value several times in a class. So I want to use Enum.GetName() to set it to a string variable which is no problem. I just do it like so...

```
private string MyEnumString = Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum), MyEnum.Name);
```

And it works just fine.

But I tried to protect it a little better because this particular Enum is more important that all the others and it would not be good if I accidentally changed the string value somehow so I tried to make it const like this.

```
private const string MyEnumString = Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum), MyEnum.Name);
```

To my eyes this seems fine as it should all be known at compile time.

But Visual Studio 2013 Throws an error saying the "Cannot resolve symbol GetName". I know it works when it is not marked "const".

So this leads me with two questions about this?
Why does it loose reference to the GetName enum? (After a bit of research I suspect it is something to do with GetName being a method and not a property of the Enum class but the error message just does not make sense to me)

And Finally is there a way to read the Name of MyEnum.Name to a const string other than what I am doing?

Comment: Can you use Visual Studio 2015 instead? Then you can use `nameof`...

Comment: "To my eyes this seems fine as it should all be known at compile time." - only if the compiler knows what `Enum.GetName` does, which it doesn't... (Just like it doesn't know what `Math.Sqrt` does, so `const double x = Math.Sqrt(2.0);` won't compile either.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Unfortunately we have to stick with Visual Studio 2013 for the time being but I will have to look into "nameof" as we will be going to 2015 before the end of the year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make it readonly:

```
private readonly string MyEnumString = Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum), MyEnum.Name);
```

Then it can't be changed afterwards.

You can't assign the result of calling a method to a constant; C# just doesn't allow it - the compiler would have to be calling that method at compile time, possibly before it was even compiled (and not only would it have to generate the IL, it would have to use the JIT compiler to compile that IL).

`Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum), MyEnum.Name);` is calling a method, so you can't assign the result to a constant.

[EDIT] As Jon Skeet says in a comment above, you can use `nameof` if using C#6 or later (i.e. VS2015 or later):

```
private const string MyEnumString = nameof(MyEnum.Name);
```

`nameof` works because here you are not calling an arbitrary method, but you are instead using a compiler feature to access the name of a type.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use result of the method as constant, because method evaluation can occur only at runtime. The value of the constant must be known at compile time. In order for compiler to be able to evaluate that constant, it would need to know the semantics of Enum.GetName and execute it at compile time, which is not possible

You can mark it as `static readonly` instead. That way it will be set once per type where it is declared and it cannot be changed anymore at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It may not even be known at *run-time*:

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value, the GetName method guarantees that it will return the name of one of those enumeration members. However, **it does not guarantee that it will always return the name of the same enumeration member**.

(emphasis added)

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine (Enum.GetName(typeof(Test),Test.One));
}

public enum Test
{
   Zero,
   One,
   Two,
   Uno = 1,
   Dos = 2,
}
```

I consistently get the output `Uno` for the program above.

The reason is it not known is because enums are compiled to the underlying *value*.  The call above is essentially compiled to `Enum.GetName(typeof(Test), 1)`. `GetName` looks for a member with that value to find the name.    How it does that is apparently an implementation detail that may not product consistent results.

What you *can* use for a constant in C#6 and later is `nameof`:

```
private const string MyEnumString = nameof(MyEnum.Name);
```